# show deleted items in yii

Tags: php, yii, widget

I am using codes where the deleted items are set to 1 instead of completely wiping it out(for the records sake). My question is that is anyway to separate files that have been set to 1 from the ones that are still not deleted? It is my first time using Yii so I wanted some idea on what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could copy 'deleted' items in a historical table and really delete them from primary table.

I don't see other operations about them.

Answer (score 0):

You could create another `search` (with different name of course) function in model and call this function in your grid view:

```
'dataProvider'=>$model->deletedSearch(),
```

And in the `deletedSearch` function in model:

```
public function deletedSearch()
    {

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
        ....
        $criteria->addCondition("is_deleted = 1");

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
        ));
    }
```

Thats it. Hope that helps :)

Comment: i have a dataProvider in my grid view already for the product search. How do i add another one?

Comment: I actually want to change the color and not create a new column. I tried this code and it works but creates a new column which is not i wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @revuer1 can you post some code, where you want the change the color ?